# Changing BackBuffer Height/Width in XNA - unwanted results

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, resolution

I'm a bit new to XNA, but I'll try and explain my issue as best as I can.

I want to change resolution in-game, by setting the `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight` and `graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth`.

By starting off with `graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth` set to **1920**, and `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight` set to **1080**, the game initializes fine.

However, by the press of a button, I want `graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth` set to **1280**, and `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight` set to **720**. (Both resolutions are **16:9**)

However, initializing `graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth` and `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight` in the Initialize method works fine, as you'd expect.
But by changing both values, followed by `graphics.ApplyChanges()`, **OUTSIDE** Initialize, the screen either stretches in weird ways, or do not display properly at all.

- How can I change the BackBuffer Width/Height outside Initialize?
- Why does it not go the same, if I set these in the Initialize?
- Do I have to call Initialize again?

Comment: Can you give more detail on exactly what it's doing? Or even some code for where and how you're doing the change. A screenshot or two would be nice as well.

It may not be the change itself but how your drawing your objects

Comment: It really sounds like you are missing a step somewhere, or maybe missing a `ApplyChanges`. If you can, post some code (I know it's hard to trim down xna code, but please don't post *all* your code).

Comment: Unfortunately my code of use is hard to understand, due to my use of many enums, classes, etc. In the Initialize(), I basically set the graphics.IsFullscreen = true. Later on, in the Update event, it would set the

Comment: Sorry - I'm a bit new to StackExchange, so apology if I'm hitting Enter, to make a new line, not post the comment. In the Update(), it would re-set the PreferredBackBuffer Width, and Height. Followed by graphics.ApplyChanges().

Comment: You know you can always edit your comments/posts.

Comment: Maybe you can find useful this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283294/how-to-resize-window-using-xna

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation with the OP in comments section, it would appear the issue is with setting the graphics to full screen in that it is stretching the screen in order to handle a smaller resolution.

Comment: Both 1920x1080 and 1280x720 are 16:9 ratios (multiplied with 1.5). I'm getting horizontal black bars, that takes atleast 50% of the screen. Do I need to re-set the fullscreen boolean?

Comment: Are the black bars appearing when you are not drawing anything?

And are you using the default spritebatch.Begin()?

Comment: Indeed I am using the standard spriteBatch.Begin/Draw.. To clarify, this issue occurs when the game is in FullScreen mode ONLY. `graphics.IsFullscreen` It seems the render window is stretched on it's width, and not it's height, which explains the black bars.

Comment: At this point I'm going to have to ask for a code example. Being able to run the same code you are will allow me to visual see the issue and debug the problem. If at all possible, please update your question with your code.