# Why does changing the graphics setting after doing so in the `LoadContent` method fail?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, xna-4.0

If I set the graphics settings in the `Initialize` method and then in the `Update` method, like so:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
    base.Initialize();
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Everything is fine.

However, when I move the code to my `LoadContent` method like so:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    graphics.ApplyChanges();
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

I get an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Must call BeginScreenDeviceChange before calling EndScreenDeviceChange

This doesn't make much sense to me, since I'm doing the same thing in both. It was my understanding that the `LoadContent` method was simply called after the `Initialize` method. What is happening between those calls that messes up the `GraphicsDeviceManager`?

Answer (score 0):

You're messing up some of XNA's internal plumbing. Normally XNA should hook up events to call those methods on `GameWindow` when the graphics device is created/destroyed, with correct pairing. But, because you're changing the graphics device somewhere you shouldn't be, you've somehow caused it to fail.

To answer the question about your specific case: What is happening is that `base.Initialize()` calls `LoadContent` *after* it has set up those events. Your call to `ApplyChanges` has moved from before the events get hooked up, to after.

Not that it matters, because ***neither* version of your code is correct**. That it seems to work in the first version is just good luck. **Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287316/165500)**, which explains how to set up and change the graphics device *correctly*.

Comment: I've never had any problem with setting the graphics settings in the `Initialize` method. I don't see why it shouldn't be done.

Comment: A couple of reasons: First of all, it's wasteful - it causes the graphics device to get set-up, torn-down, and re-set-up. You could just set it up correctly the first time. Secondly it can cause substantial flickering in [some cases](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8024424/165500). Finally it's just plain wrong - the API isn't designed to work like that. If you play fast-and-loose with the API, you're bound to hit some weird edge case - as you seem to in your original question. Like I said - it's just good luck that it doesn't fail outright. It's best to take the correct, well-tested API path.